# create react app: Reorder Style tag so that css is in the correct order

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd, styled-components

I use `create react app` to build my web application and I use `ant design` components. I use `styled-components` to further customize the styling. Everything is good right now.

However, when I try to change primary color following [this](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app), I noticed that my css rule (from `styled-components`) being overridden by the newly compiled one (from less, default `antd` style with changed primary color).

When I open the developer console, the compiled css is in the last position. When I drag up and reorder the style tag in the developer console, it gives me the correct display. How to config so that the `antd` css come before `styled-components` one?

This is my `config-overrides.js`

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#333' },
  }),
);
```